# While pulling the rows from the SQL server view needs to update a table based on some condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to pull some table(let say table A) data by using a view. In that case based on some condition, I need to update the table A and will return the rows from that table.

Please let me know if anybody knows the solution for this...

Comment: This sounds a bit confusing.  It would be helpful to us if you could provide some examples of - the starting data in table A, the updated data, the data in the result set and the condition which initiates this behaviour.

Comment: Also, are you thinking that the view will handle all this?

Comment: Table A will be like below
Name Ids Flag
A 1,2,3 0
B 5,6,7 1

If I write a view for pulling the above data then I need to check the flag column like if the flag is 0 then need to update that row with some values to the Ids column and the same has to be returned

Answer (score 0):

Let's flip the question. How about you use MERGE to update what you need in TableA, including some records that don't necessarily need changing, and then use the OUTPUT clause to turn your data modification into something that returns data?